# 403 Forbidden Error using nginx

Tags: web-applications, nginx

I'm trying to get an nginx server going for web-app testing purposes, but for some reason I keep receiving a 403: Forbidden error. I've stripped this down to what I think is there bare bones of what should work, meaning there's just an index.html file, no back end server or anything else. Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /Users/turner/Documents/;
        index        index.html;

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

}
include servers/*;
```

There is an index.html in my Documents folder, so that isn't the problem. I've looked at a plethora of questions on here and elsewhere about this issue, but either they don't deal with my problem or I am not yet familiar enough with nginx to make use of them.

If there's any further information I can provide that would make this question better please let me know.

Comment: Can you please check your error logs files and let us know what exact error are you getting in nginx error logs file of your domain ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the nginx user hasn't got the suitable rights to access this directory (or it is encrypted e.g. with ecryptfs)

Comment: Hi, I just saw this - sorry! Is there a way to check if this is the problem? And if it was any idea how I'd go about rectifying it?

Comment: `sudo -u www-data ls -la /Users/turner/Documents/`